# Print stack trace without a try-catch block

Tags: java, junit, stack-trace

So I have a selenium test which I want to print the stack trace to a new .txt file when the test fails yet I want to accomplish this WITHOUT using a try catch block because I want the line of code "JUnit.runClasses(Myclass.class)" to return false when I run it, yet also print the stacktrace to the text file. Anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`Thread.dumpStack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack()) prints the current stack to standard error.

There are other `Thread` methods that can return stack details, read through the API page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all method calls printed to a file than the following might be what you want:

```
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter("file.txt");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    StackTraceElement[] e = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (StackTraceElement element : e) {
        writer.println(element.toString());
    }
    writer.close();
```

The Exception doesn't get thrown unless there is some issue with output file, so the method still returns in the scenario you described.